# How to set multiple paths in URI builder?

Tags: java, url, uri, rest-assured

How to make a URL for the below type? I'm doing something like below. If I send both the "path" and "PathSegments" values, it takes only PathSegment's values and not path's.

"https://localhost/api/customer" + "/" +{Id1} + "/" + "summary?invoiceId=" + {Id2} + "&page=0&pageSize=100&q=" + {Id3};

```
   public static String abcd(String path, List<NameValuePair> paramsLst, String...pathSegment){

    URIBuilder builder1 = new URIBuilder()

        .setScheme("https")
        .setHost("localhost")
        .setPath(path) // "/api/customer"
        .addParameter(paramsLst)
        .setPathSegments(pathSegment);

    return builder1.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I think that your problem is that you are using the wrong terminology for what you are doing.  This is NOT multiple paths.  It is a single path with multiple components in the path.  (A URI can only ever have one path.  That's what the spec says.  Setting *multiple* paths in a URI *does not make sense*.)  Anyway, if you use the wrong terminology, you will have difficulty understanding the API javadocs, the tutorials, etc ... that are using the correct terminology.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @stephen. That means "path" and "pathSegments" can never be used together?

Comment: That depends on the `URIBuilder` API you are using, and you haven't been specific about that.  But if you are talking about Apache `URIBulder`, that is correct.  A `setPath` or `setPathSegments` call will *replace* the previous path / path segments.

Comment: (If the javadoc is unclear, read the source code.  That's what I did ...)

Comment: I am doing API automation with rest-assured. I wanted to find an alternate way to replace the approach where we write the complete URL in one line, like the one I mentioned in the question. So, I thought of doing it with Apache URIBuilder. But it takes a lot of lines in the code if I have to create the query parameters list which makes the main test case code lengthy. Can you suggest any other way apart from URIBuilder which I can use or this one should be fine?

Comment: There are a number of URI Builder APIs. I suggest you Google their javadocs, read them, and work out which ones meet your needs.  (Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try so:

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();

uriBuilder.setScheme("https");
uriBuilder.setHost("localhost");
uriBuilder.setPathSegments("api", "customer", "id1Value", "summary");
uriBuilder.addParameters(paramsList);
```

Or you can try to use `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder`:

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
        .scheme("https")
        .host("localhost")
        .path("api/customer/{id1}/summary")
        .queryParams(params) // MultiValueMap
        .buildAndExpand("id1Value") // value for {id1} in the path
        .toUri();
```